# awk to print some parameters of a line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have lines in a file in linux, and i am trying print the line without the `|` and without some parameters

```
$cat file 
2013-07-15,Provider 1.99,3|30000055|2347|0,12222,1,3,0,0,0,19,aaa,bbb
2013-07-15,Provider 1.99,3|30000055|2347|0,12222,44,12,0,0,0,33,aaa,bbb
```

and i need the output like:

```
2013-07-15,Provider,2347,12222,1,3,0,0,0,19,aaa,bbb
2013-07-15,Provider,2347,12222,44,12,0,0,0,33,aaa,bbb
```

and i am trying with awk, but i have some problems.

Comment: please include your awk code and sample (problematic) output. Otherwise we're left to guess about why you are having trouble and what you need to  understand in order to move forward. Good luck.

Comment: cat file | sed s/" "/\_/g | awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} {print $1,$2}', but i am trying do other awk in $2, but it is a mistake, i do not know how do it

Comment: in the future, don't expect people to have to decode messages inside of comment, please edit your question! please!? Use the `{}` editing tool at the top left of the input box to format code as code (you are doing that now with your data, (a good thing!) ). All that said, +1 becuase you included easy sample data and required output from that data!!! Answers below are good. Continued good luck to all.

Answer (score 1):

If your lines have similar pattern you would to retain then you can do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$2="Provider";$3=2347}1' file
```

If you don't know what the patterns are then here is a more generic one:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{split($2,a,/ /);split($3,b,/\|/);$2=a[1];$3=b[3]}1' file
```

If it doesn't solve your problem, I am pretty sure it would help you guide to get one.

Answer (score 1):

Using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed 's/ [^|]*|[^|]*|\([^|]*\)|[^,]/,\1/' input
```

and some shorter version:

```
sed 's/ .*|\([^|]*\)|[^,]*/,\1/' input
```

and even shorter:

```
sed 's/ .*|\(.*\)|[^,]*/,\1/' input
```

Answer (score 1):

Use awk, and let blank or comma or pipe be the field separators:

```
awk -F '[[:blank:],|]' -v OFS=, '{
    print $1,$2,$6,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16
}' file
```

```
2013-07-15,Provider,2347,12222,1,3,0,0,0,19,aaa,bbb
2013-07-15,Provider,2347,12222,44,12,0,0,0,33,aaa,bbb
```